# how to get R data in progress?

Tags: java, r

I want to get data from R in progress with using java and 'RServe'.
But I can't get data until R finish performing process for eval function as below.

If it will take long time to perform in R, I can't confirm the processing status.
Could you show the ways to get processing information from R.

```
RConnection c = new RConnection();
REXP x = c.eval("R.version.string");
System.out.println(x.asString());
```

Thanks in advance.